# How to move AntD Menu Submenu Arrow to the front to the menu name

Tags: reactjs, antd

How can I move the submenu expand arrow showing in the below image to the front?

[image]

Comment: Can you add some code plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override `antd` styles, 1st we need to inspect the elements and identify which styles/classNames applied. Then override these styles as we want.

In this scenario, Wrap your `<Menu/>` component from a `div` as below and apply below styles to `div`.

```
<div className="menuMain">
  <Menu
    onClick={onClick}
    style={{
      width: 256
    }}
    defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}
    defaultOpenKeys={["sub1"]}
    mode="inline"
    items={items}
  />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menuMain > ant-menu-submenu-expand-icon,
.ant-menu-submenu-arrow {
    right: 240px;
 }
```

Check here for [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inline-menu-antd-arrowicon-72859826-fcxxjw?file=/demo.js) example.